# Error al descargar base de datos a Android Studio

Tags: android, base-de-datos

He estado realizando un código para poder descargar todo el contenido de una base de datos local con ***xampp***. El código en ***Android Studio*** es este:

```
public void descargarDatos(String url){
        nombre.clear();
        apellido.clear();

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando datos...");
        progressDialog.show();
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {
                if( i == 200 ){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try{
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(bytes));
                        editInformacion.setText("");
                        for( int j=0; j<jsonArray.length(); j++ ){
                            nombre.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("nombre"));
                            apellido.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("apellido"));
                            editInformacion.setText( nombre.get(j).toString() + "    " );
                            editInformacion.setText( nombre.get(j).toString() + "\n" );
                        }
                    }catch( JSONException e ){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Y el archivo en ***php*** que realiza la consulta es este:

```
<?php 
    include 'conexion.php';
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $consulta = "select * from data where nombre = '$nombre'";
    $res = $conexion -> query($consulta);
    while( $fila = $res ->fetch_array() ){
        $usuario[] = array_map( 'utf8_encode', $fila );
    }
    echo json_encode($usuario);
    $res -> close();
?>
```

El error que obtengo es :

> org.json.JSONException: Value

El cual se encuentra en esta instrucción:

> JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(bytes));

Comment: Te sugiero que antes de realizar JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(bytes)); imprime el valor de new String(bytes) y agregalo a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es simple, lo que obtienes mediante `new String(bytes)` para usar en esta linea de código:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(new String(bytes));
```

no es un JSONArray, incluso puede ser probablemente que sea un JSONObject o incluso que no sea información en formato json.

---

Recuerda que la información JSON puede estar definida como :

> **- Si el json inicia con `{` se considera como objeto Json.**
>
> **- Si el json inicia con `[` es considerado como Arreglo Json.**

Por el error obtenido seguramente el valor de `new String(bytes)`  no es en realidad un `JSONArray`.